# String split operations in C# 

Tags: c#

I have a string say `string s ="C:\\Data"` , I have an array which contains some strings containg "C:\Data" in the beginning i.e. `string[] arr = new {"C:\\Data\abc.xml","C:\\Data\Test\hello.cs"};`.

I have to remove the string "C:\Data" from each entry and have to combine it with another string say `string fixed = "D:\\Data"`.

What is the best way to do it, please help as I am a new programmer in C#.

Comment: Which version of c# are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Replace` is perhaps *not* what you need, as it would replace *all* the occurrences of `C:\Data` in your string, whereas you need only that at the *beginning*.

I would suggest the following:

```
string s ="C:\\Data";
string s1 = "D:\\Data";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].StartsWith(s))
        arr[i] = s1 + arr[i].Remove(s.Length);
}
```

Comment: Good point.  For example, if this is a PATH variable that contains many occurences of C:\Data paths separated by semicolons, then Replace would replace all of them.  This could be desirable or not, depending on Indigo's needs.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure that all of the elements in your array begin with "C:\Data", then it's pretty simple:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
   arr[i] = arr[i].Replace("C:\\Data" , "D:\\Data");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining LINQ and string.Replace():

```
arr.Select(s => s.Replace("C:\\Data", "D:\\Data").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

String.replace would take care of that pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
  arr[i] = arr[i].Replace("C:\\Data", "D:\\Data");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use LINQ and do

```
String[] newStrings = arr.Select(oldString => fixed + oldString.Replace(s, ""))
                         .ToArray()
```

Note that `fixed` is a keyword in c# and therefore a bad choice for a variable name.

Comment: This example is incomplete doesn't quite do what @Indigo is asking.